# Displaying terminal output in columns for efficiently viewing more output

Tags: unix, pager, tmux

Suppose I have large amounts of log output or something that I want to keep tabs on, to be able to view simultaneously as much output as possible.

I have lots of screen real-estate, and to make better use of it I'd like to be able to set up a special buffer that will *vertically* wrap the terminal output, so it looks like a column layout (as in a book or webpage).

This way I can e.g. dedicate an entire widescreen monitor to three columns of output, which can simultaneously display up to three times as much vertical output as normal from the same stream. I think this is something that tmux could support well, though it may cause slightly more load on network traffic due to the split nature of moving text.

The best case scenario would be if tmux already supports this via some option, but if not, maybe it can be scripted! Is it possible to "retrieve" the contents of tmux's history buffer for a particular pane programmatically? I'd be averse to a script that would need to make a call to `tmux` on every incoming line of output but it could still be worth it for slow output logs.

Perhaps this isn't even something that needs tmux, perhaps this is the within the feature-space of a pager program. Vim probably won't be able to handle it because I will require this to support ANSI color code display (which Vim just can't display that well).

The motivation here is to make better use of horizontal space. In a way it is the extension of the function of the pager program into the second dimension. If I can simply buy more monitors to be able to see more data simultaneously without having to manipulate my software to show me different sections of my data, then I can work a little bit more efficiently by cutting out all the scrolling around I always do.

**Looking back and forth >> setting up panes and scrolling two buffers in order to look back and forth >> scrolling back and forth in a single buffer**

no manipulation >> manipulation once in the beginning >> manipulation on each iteration

More contemplation: 
I just thought of a neat idea to get this functionality built quick-and-dirty, is if I can come up with a way to set up a pager (or even just `cat`, really) to show the last page (which is a trivial case of not doing anything to the output), show the second to last page, show the third to last page, etc. These can be composed together inside a set of tmux panes. What happens, then, is as a new line comes in, all these views get scrolled up, and we have the illusion that they are all a contiguous display of a single buffer even though it is not. So this would be a tmux based hack that thankfully does not require some sort of tmux call with each new line... tmux lets us query panes for their height so we can figure out which "section" to display in each buffer. If the buffers can be made to scroll through their histories synchronously, the entire set of "columns" can be scrolled as well.

Answer (score 0):

The above works fine if you're looking at three files, but it sounds like you're looking at one. I wrote some python that should do the right thing (as a substitute for tail).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import time, os, sys

fname = sys.argv[1]
lines_per_page = 50
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    page_from = int(sys.argv[2])
    pages_per_page = int(sys.argv[3])
else:
    page_from = 0
f = open(fname)
f.seek(os.stat(fname).st_size)

b = []

while 1:
    where = f.tell()
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        time.sleep(1)
        f.seek(where)
    else:
        # keep a buffer
        if page_from > 0:
            b.append(line)
            front = lines_per_page * page_from
            if len(b) > front:
                print b[-front],
        else:
            print line,
```

You would invoke this as `tail.py file 0 num_of_rows_in_your_term`, then increment by 1 for each of the other vertical panes.

Answer (score 0):

I came across [this gem](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/View_text_file_in_two_columns) the other day (about 2 months ago). My vimrc contains this magic:

```
:noremap <silent> <Leader>c :<C-u>let @z=&so<CR>:set so=0 noscb<CR>:bo vs<CR>Ljzt:setl scb<CR><C-w>p:setl scb<CR>:let &so=@z<CR>
```

Very very cool, and is quite powerful because it's Vim. The only drawback would be that Vim can't really be used effectively to view actual raw terminal output (which may include ANSI color codes which is something that Vim is particularly horrible at handling), but for most purposes, viewing (and editing) very large source files, etc., this works great.

Edit: I'm noticing that this actually does not really answer my question which was basically how to better fill my screen with many columns worth of terminal output (say, output from scripts or compiles or logs) which this vim buffer thing isn't really very great at.

There is some potential for it though, whatever log can get piped into a file and then the Vim can be scripted to constantly refresh and load it in to a multi-column buffer.